# is $\sin(\sin^{-1}(x))$ always equal to $x$?

Tags: trigonometry

since $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is the opposite of $\sin(x)$ I think this should be true. however when I input some test numbers into the calculators, sometimes it says error. because of this, I would like to know whether this is true or not.

Comment: What do you mean by always? Do you know what $sin^{-1}x$ means at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the numbers which give you error. Then think about what inputs $\sin^{-1}$ accepts. Once this is cleared up, then yes, you will always get $x$ back.

Comment: so if my calculator accepted complex numbers I would always get x back???

Comment: @datboi You get some issues at $x = \pm 1$, and the complex $\sin^{-1}$ is multivalued, so you need to pick a branch (which any calculator will have done already), but otherwise, I would think so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

$y=\sin^{-1}x$ will be defined if $-1\le x\le1$

and $-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$ using [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

then $\sin(y)=x$

Comment: okay, so you are telling me including only real numbers, is it true for all instances if y is able to be a complex number??

Comment: @datboi, If we permit complex values, then the restriction is not required.

Comment: @datboi If we have a complex number, say $(a+bi)$, then $$sin(y) = sin(a+bi) = sin(a)cos(bi) + cos(a)sin(bi) = sin(a)cosh(b) +i .cos(a)sinh(b)$$